# wp_nav_menu() to display current page and its subitems of depth = 1

Tags: wordpress

Here's what I'm trying to do. Let's say I have a menu that looks like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Page #1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Page #1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Sub-Page #1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Sub-Page #2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Page #2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Page #3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="#">Page #2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Page #3</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I'd like to do is use wp_nav_menu to display only the page the user is currently viewing and its subitems, so for example if someone's on Sub-Page #1 or on one of its subitems (Sub-Sub-Page #1 or #2) the generated menu should look like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Page #1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Sub-Page #1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Sub-Page #2</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

If the user is currently on a Page #1 the generated menu should look like this:

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Page #1</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Page #1</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Page #2</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Sub-Page #3</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
</ul>
```

Is it possible to achieve something like this via wp_nav_menu or any other way for that matter? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve something like this via "get_posts". Just pass parameter "post_parent" in query arguments and you will get all child page.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/get_posts

```
<ul>
  <?php global $post;
  $args = array( 'posts_per_page' => -1, 'post_parent'=> get_the_ID() );  
$myposts = get_posts( $args );
foreach ( $myposts as $post ) : setup_postdata( $post ); ?>
<li>
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
</li>
<?php endforeach;  ?>
</ul>
```

you can get same goal via wp_query. 
https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Post_.26_Page_Parameters

Comment: Sadly the above solution does not return any output for me - nothing gets displayed in other words. I'll look into the WP_Query, thank you.

Comment: have you pass current page id to post_parent parameter in args?

Comment: Yep, I passed $post->ID in and nothing gets outputted.